# Create a google map using a class not an ID

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to create a google map using class instead of Id.

This is the original code from google developers
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#maps_map_simple-javascript

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

===========================

What I'm trying is to do like this way but it doesn't work

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector(".map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lab1 - Educational Institution Map</title>

        <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDoH3oyYR5nzERWlIBQ4XLVZLtm63ZoIzc&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
        <script src="education.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">

        <style>
          
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <div class="map"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are missing the CSS on the `.map` class name (you need to set a height on that element) unless it is in the `css/css.css` file that is linked in your HTML. Simply correct this in your code and if that was in the linked CSS file, then please provide a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your map div doesn't have a size, you are missing the css from the working example:

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

But since you are using class rather than id, use `.map` rather than `#map`.

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
.map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

**code snippet:**

```js
let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.querySelector(".map"), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.397,
      lng: 150.644
    },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

.map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Lab1 - Educational Institution Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```